# Linq equivalent of for in foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I'm borrowing code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283866/different-ways-of-using-selectmany) as I went there for inspiration.  I have a list of objects, the object has an integer property and I want to foreach the list and the loop the number of integers.

It's a very basic for inside a foreach but I suspect I could use a SelectMany but can't get it working.  The following code works but I would like a linq version.

```
//set up some data for our example
var tuple1 = new { Name = "Tuple1", Count = 2 };
var tuple2 = new { Name = "Tuple2", Count = 3 };


//put the tuples into a collection
var tuples = new [] { tuple1, tuple2 };

foreach(var item in tuples)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: There is no `Values` property in your anonymous type.

Comment: Values should have been count, changed now.

Comment: LinQ does not have a `ForEach` method because that would be against LinQ's very "functional" nature. .Net's `.ForEach()` is really a member of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, which is not part of LinQ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var flattened = tuples.SelectMany(t => Enumerable.Repeat(t.Name, t.Count));

foreach(var word in flattened)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: @RobertHarvhey All fairness to spender, it was what I asked for but you may be right.  I will measure and possibly change to for but I wanted to know how to do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : that would be a question for the OP. I would venture that familiarity with Linq doesn't make this any more opaque than a more verbose approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SelectMany`; you simply need to generate sequences:

```
tuples.SelectMany(t => Enumerable.Repeat(t.Name, t.Count))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Values` property in your anonymous type. But i assume that you mean the `Count` property instead and you want to repeat the name this number. You can either use `Enumerable.Range` or `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
IEnumerable<String> tupleNames = tuples
    .Select(t => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Repeat(t.Name, t.Count)));
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tupleNames));
```

Output:

```
Tuple1
Tuple1
Tuple2
Tuple2
Tuple2
```

Comment: Maybe i have misunderstood your requirement. I'm avoiding a `foreach`, so the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

There is no linq equivalent of a `foreach`.  You should use an actual `foreach` to iterate an `IEnumerable` and perform an action on each item.

Comment: It will more than likely be a list I will be working with than an array, I shouldn't have copied that code.

Comment: @PaulMcCowat That wouldn't change my answer.  If you want to iterate an `IEnumerable` and perform an action, say, writing some information out to the console, then you should use `foreach`.